# How to conditionally render components in React based on state changes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React application and I need to conditionally render components based on state changes. Specifically, I want to show different components or elements depending on the value of a state variable. For example, when the user clicks a button, I want to display a form, and when the form is submitted, I want to show a success message.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

I set up two state variables

```
 const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(true);
 const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false);
```

I could not figure out how the `handleSubmit` function should be written to display the form only when the `showForm` state variable is true and when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(true);
  const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false);

  // Function to handle form submission
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your form submission logic here
    // For example, you can make an API call to submit the form data

    // Assuming the form submission is successful, update the state to show the success message
    setShowForm(false);
    setShowSuccessMessage(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Conditionally render the form or success message based on state */}
      {showForm && (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {/* Your form elements go here */}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      )}

      {showSuccessMessage && <div>Success! Your form has been submitted.</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Explanation:

We are using the showForm state variable to determine whether to display the form or not.
Initially, showForm is set to true, so the form will be rendered on the first render.
When the form is submitted, the handleSubmit function is called, which updates the state to hide the form (setShowForm(false)) and show the success message (setShowSuccessMessage(true)).
When showSuccessMessage becomes true, the success message will be rendered due to the conditional rendering in the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really provide insight on what you are trying to do but I'll just provide an example to help you out. Say you have a form component that you want to render conditionally in your app,

```
export default App() {
     const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(true);
     const [showSuccessMessage, setShowSuccessMessage] = useState(false);

     return (
         // if showForm is true, render form component
         {showForm && <FormComponent />}
         // if showSuccessMessage is true, render success message         
         {showSuccessMessage && <h1>Form submitted successfully</h1>}
     )
}
```

The components will only be rendered when the state variables are true. There are a lot of ways you can implement conditional rendering, this is one of them.